# A step in the proof that a connected manifold is homogeneous

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $X$ be a connected manifold, and $b \in X$ a point, and define the set
$$A = \{ a \in X : \exists f : X \approx X, \ f(a) = b \} \ .$$
Consider a point $c \in A$. Since $X$ is a manifold, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $c$ such that there is a homeomorphism $g : U \approx B^n$. Now let $d \in U$ be any other point.

I have the following theorem at my disposal : for any $p,q \in B^n$ there exists a homeomorhpism $h : \overline{B}^n \approx \overline{B}^n$ such that $h(p) = q$, and $h|_{\partial \overline{B}^n} = \operatorname{id}$.

Now, using the above theorem I would like to construct an automorphism which maps the point $d$ to the point $b$. However, I am unable to turn my thoughts into rigorous mathematics. Using the homeomorphism $g$  we know that $g(c), g(d) \in B^n$, so we can construct a homoemorhpism $h : \overline{B}^n \approx \overline{B}^n$ such that $h(g(d)) = g(c)$, and since $g$ is a homeomorphism we have $c = g^{-1} (h(g(d)))$. Now, since $c \in A$ we know that $f(c) = b \iff f(g^{-1} (h(g(d)))) = b$. Now I am stuck. I would like to glue some of the homeomorphisms above and $f$  in order to make an automorphism, but I am not sure how to do this. I know of the pasting lemma, which allows us to glue together continuous functions on closed sets, but in my case my sets seem to be open.

Any help?

Comment: How can you glue them with $f$ when you don't have an $f$ yet? Your job is to construct $f$. Note that $g^{-1}\circ h \circ g$ is a local homeomorphism on $U$. Now choose some new $x$ on the boundary of $U$ and consider a chart about it. Can you use that chart to extend the local homeomorphism to some neighborhood of $x$? If so, then examine what happens if you maximumly extend your homeomorphism. Is its domain open? is it closed?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. If I take a point $x \in \partial U$ and the chart $(\varphi_x, V)$ then I guess I want to try and extend the local homeomorphism to the set $U \cup V$? Using the same construction, I can construct a local homeomorphism on $V$, however now the points $U \cap V$ are problematic since I have to choose which homeomorphism to use while mapping them. Any additional hints for the first part, so the extension to some neighborhood?